# Creating Hourly Counts Across Different Shifts

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sum, ssms

I'm trying to create a query that divides a shifts production into hourly counts that can be ran through multiple shifts yet have the first hours of each shift fall under the same counts.

```
    Sum(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[creation_time]) = '1' THEN quantity_increment_D ELSE 0 END) C1,
    Sum(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[creation_time]) = '2' THEN quantity_increment_D ELSE 0 END) C2,
    Sum(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,[creation_time]) = '3' THEN quantity_increment_D ELSE 0 END) C3,
```

This query works fine, in my report, for the first shift of the day, but second and third shifts won't restart on C1.  I essentially need to ask something to the effect of:

```
If(shift_id_S)='1' then sum(quantity_increment_D) where (creation_time) between '00:00:00' and'07:59:59' as C1
If(shift_id_S)='2' then sum(quantity_increment_D) where (creation_time) between '08:00:00' and'15:59:59' as C1  
If(shift_id_S)='3' then sum(quantity_increment_D) where (creation_time) between '16:00:00' and'23:59:59' as C1
If(shift_id_S)='4' then sum(quantity_increment_D) where (creation_time) between '00:00:00' and'11:59:59' as C1
If(shift_id_S)='5' then sum(quantity_increment_D) where (creation_time) between '12:00:00' and'23:59:59' as C1
```

If I can get help with this part of the query, I can take care of the rest of the counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your issue us. Do you just need to figure out the logic? Your second query doesn't seem to match what you were doing with your first query though.

You can add your other criteria to your CASE statement and maybe use another CASE for the times so you don't need separate ones. I haven't used much MySQL but this should work:

```
Sum(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HH, [creation_time]) BETWEEN 
CASE WHEN shift_id_S ='1' OR shift_id_S ='4' THEN '00'
     WHEN shift_id_S ='2' THEN '08'
     WHEN shift_id_S ='3' THEN '16'
     WHEN shift_id_S ='5' THEN '12' END
AND 
CASE WHEN shift_id_S ='3' OR shift_id_S ='5' THEN '23'
     WHEN shift_id_S ='1' THEN '07'
     WHEN shift_id_S ='2' THEN '15'
     WHEN shift_id_S ='4' THEN '11' END
THEN quantity_increment_D ELSE 0 END) AS C1
```

Then duplicate this for the other Shifts (C2, C3...).

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Yes it was 2 different queries I was writing.  I wrote the first to make sure I was pulling the write data, the second one I couldn't figure out the proper syntax to write.  Thanks again!